# Why is Rails /Thin not able to interpret large POST bodies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post

On our client, we send a POST body as follows to a route on Rails:

```
names[0][name]=Joe Random&names[0][id]=123&names[1][name]=Joe Random2&names[1][id]=124
```

This is properly encoded in the real request, just wanted to show what it's supposed to look like. In the action that handles this request, we see the result we expect when logging `params[:names]`:

```
{"0"=>{"name"=>"Joe Random", "id"=>"123"}, "1"=>{"name"=>"Joe Random2", "id"=>"124"}}
```

However, if this POST body becomes very large, something like this:

`names[0][name]=Joe Random&names[0][id]=123` ... `names[5000][name]=Joe Random5000&names[5000][id]=5124`

And we log `params[:names]`, it's now `nil`, even though you can see the POST body is there by logging `request.raw_post`. Also, there is nothing unusual about the data in the large or small request because I can parse it by hand.

Anybody have an idea why this would be the case? If it helps, I have `protect_from_forgery` on. Also, I'm on Rails 3.0.9.

Comment: What server do you use? Have you tried multiple ones to see if that affects this behavior? Try installing thin, mongrel, webrick, etc.

Comment: This is thin, on Heroku.